# When do photos expire on iOS in /tmp/ folder

Tags: ios, iphone, temporary-files

When using the camera on and iOS App, iPhone saves temporary photos to this folder:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3823983289389/tmp/cdv_photo_138.jpg

When do these expire? Is there a set period of time after which iOS deletes these? And how long it is or can you adjust it programmatically?

Comment: You can do it programmatically, but Apple also does it after some period of time, my question what is that period of time and can we manipulate it programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no control over the lifetime of files in the `tmp/` folder. All you know is that the OS may purge such files any time your app is not running.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28):

> Put temporary data in the `tmp/` directory. Temporary data comprises any data that you do not need to persist for an extended period of time. Remember to delete those files when you are done with them so that they do not continue to consume space on the user’s device. The system will periodically purge these files when your app is not running; therefore, you cannot rely on these files persisting after your app terminates.